# For $f :\mathbb R \to \mathbb R $, there exists an $(a,b)$, such that $f$ is bounded on a sequence with limit $x$, for all $x\in(a,b)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, limits, baire-category

I want to prove the following.

Let $f : \mathbb R  \mapsto \mathbb R $. Show that there *exists* an interval $(a,b) \in \mathbb R $  and $c >0 $: such that for any $x \in (a,b) $ there is a sequence $\{x _n \} $ with $x _n \to x $ and $|f(x _n )| \le c $.

(no assumption on $f $ being continuous )

I have no idea how to go about to prove this...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A wild guess, can Baire category theorem be used?

Comment: Consider the sets $A_n=\bigl\{\, x\mid |f(x)|\le n\,\bigr\}$. The closure of some $A_n$ contains an open interval. Show that this gives what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be can dealt with rather easily if you now [Baire Category Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem).

As $f[\mathbb R]\subset \mathbb R$, then $\mathbb R=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}f^{-1}(-n,n)$. Let $F_n=\overline{f^{-1}(-n,n)}$, and observe now that $\mathbb R$ is a countable union of closed sets. Baire's Theorem provides that at least one of the has nonempty interior, i.e.,
there are $a<b$ and $n\in\mathbb N$, such that
$$
(a,b)\subset \overline{f^{-1}(-n,n)}.
$$

Clearly, this $(a,b)$ does our job for $c=n$.